# Is this pythonic? Class self variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Long story short, I need to write a data analysing tool using mainly OOP principles. I'm not quite a beginner at python but still not the best. I wrote a function which returned true or false value based on what the user inputted (below):

```
def secondary_selection():
    """This prints the options the user has to manipulate the data"""
    print("---------------------------")
    print("Column Statistics        [C]")
    print("Graph Plotting       [G]")
    d = input(str("Please select how you want the data to be processed:")).lower()
    #  Returns as a true/false boolean as it's easier
    if d == "c":
        return True
    elif d == "g":
        return False
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid input")
```

This function works the way I want it to, but I then tried to import it into different file for use with a class (below):

```
class Newcastle:
    def __init__(self, data, key_typed):
        self.data = data[0]
        self.key_typed = key_typed

    def newcastle_selection(self):
        # If function returns True
        if self:            
            column_manipulation()
        # If function returns False
        if not self:
            graph_plotting()
```

The `newcastle_selection(self)` function takes the `secondary_selection()` function as a argument, but the only way I got it to work was the `if self` statement. As writing something like `if true` lead to both the `column_manipulation` and the `graph_plotting` functions being printed. 
I am wondering if there's any better way to write this as I am not quite a beginner at python but still relatively new to it.

Disclaimer: This is for a first year course, and I asked this as a last result.

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of your code in the question please.  As it is we can't tell the exact structure of the code.

Comment: There should be no `if self`. Self is always there and it is an implicit argument. You should not pass it yourself. Unless you want the function to be a `staticmethod` then leave self and add an extra argument for whatever it is you pass to `newcastle_selection`.

Comment: @PaulRooney so i should write something like `newcastle_selection(self, x)` so that it would be `if x == True` instead of `if self:`

Comment: Your code do not matches with your description of it, "_The `newcastle_selection(self)` function takes the `secondary_selection()` function as a argument_". Did I forgot how to read Python within the night or are we ok this is not true in your code?

Comment: I am not sure if a code like `if self` makes sense in `OOPS`. The whole point is that `self` is there and the functions are called from the context of the `self` :-) Or in other words, `class` functions are called from the context of the `objects`. I like to think of a `class` as having a `state` and a `behaviour`.

Comment: I would suggest follow KISS. Question being that *why* passing **method** which can be implemented more cleanly using Class itself. I would suggest try using methods as params to class objects only when they are dynamically validated and used (as in APIs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood really well your code structure, but it looks like a little [factory](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) could helps you:

```
def column_manipulation():
    print("Column manipulation")


def graph_plotting():
    print("Graph plotting")


class Newcastle:
    def __init__(self, data, func):
        self.data = data[0]
        self._func = func

    def newcastle_selection(self):
        return self._func()

    @classmethod
    def factorize(cls, data, key_typed):
        if key_typed is True:
            return cls(data, column_manipulation)
        elif key_typed is False:
            return cls(data, graph_plotting)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Newcastle.factorize expects bool, {} given'.format(
                type(key_typed).__name__
            ))


nc = Newcastle.factorize(["foo"], True)
nc.newcastle_selection()

nc = Newcastle.factorize(["foo"], False)
nc.newcastle_selection()
```

Output

```
Column manipulation
Graph plotting
```

The main idea is to define your class in a generic way, so you store a `function` given as `__init__` parameter within `self._func` and just call it in `newcastle_selection`.

Then, you create a `classmethod` that takes your data & `key_typed`. This method is in charge of choosing which function (`column_manipulation` or `graph_plotting`) will be used for the current instance.

So you don't store useless values like `key_typed` in your class and don't have to handle specific cases everywhere, only in `factorize`.

Cleaner and powerful I think (and btw it answer your question "*Is this pythonic*", this is).

Comment: This is cleaner @jszabo

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and basic example of **secondary_selection** method using class. This would help probably.

```
class castle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ''

    def get_input(self):
        print("1: Column Statistics")
        print("2: Graph Plotting")
        self.data = input("Please select how you want the data to be processed: ")

    def process(self):
        if self.data == 1:
            return self.column_manipulation()
        else:
            return self.graph_plotting()

    def column_manipulation(self):
        return True

    def graph_plotting(self):
        return False


c = castle()
c.get_input()
result = c.process()
print(result)
```